# Which is the better method in Android for creating a dynamic list?

Tags: android, list, view

If you are creating a very dynamic list, say, where every row can have a different set of input types plus optional buttons, and the list length is based on another dynamic value, is it better to do this in a list adapter or creating a custom view in a scroll window?

After struggling with list adapters for quite a while now something finally occurred to me- this seems dumb. It seems like I am going through a lot of work keeping track of what spinner is set to what value, which row was clicked and so forth.

For example, say you are showing something like a contacts screen with various details that can be entered about a contact. Some rows will have text inputs (name, address etc), some will have spinners (ie. state, group), some will have checkboxes (like 'favorite' or something). Also, there is an 'add' button that allows you to add another field to edit. Is it worth making this in a list adapter or is it better to populate a custom view, and if the "add" button is clicked, we re-create the custom view, adding a view of the type they want to add?

I hope this is clear.

Comment: I do not know if I follow, but have you seen [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) method?

Answer (score 0):

ListViews (and List Adapters) are meant for data that is to be displayed in mainly similar views. For your example, it is much easier and more natural to have a predefined layout file with the screen and use view visibility so select which views are to be shown. If you need to add views to the screen you can do this dynamically by using findViewById on the layout and then using it's [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method.

Let me know if you need more clarification or sample code...